Ramanujan graph element in $\mathsf{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Z}_q)$
I am trying to follow the construction of the Ramanujan graph $X^{p, q}$ given in the paper 1. The first few steps of the construction proceed as follows:

Let $p$, $q$ be two unequal primes that are congruent to $1\text{ mod }4$;
Let $i$ be an integer such that $i^2\equiv-1\text{ mod }q$;
Find all $p+1$ integer solutions to the equation $a_0^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=p$ for which $a_0>0$ is odd and $a_j$ is even for $j=1, 2, 3$;
For each such solution $\alpha = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3)$, form the matrix $\tilde{\alpha} = \left(\begin{matrix}a_0 +i a_1 & a_2+i a_3 \\ -a_2+i a_3 & a_0 - i a_1\end{matrix}\right)$ as an element of $\mathsf{PGL}(2, \mathbb{Z}_q)$.

It is then claimed that when the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=1$ then all the matrices $\tilde{\alpha}$ in fact lie in the group $\mathsf{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Z}_q)$. However, I am unable to verify this claim for the following example.
Take $p=17$, $q=13$, and $i=5$. Then $p\equiv 1 \text{ mod }4$, $q\equiv 1 \text{ mod }4$, $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=1$ and $i^2=-1\text{ mod }q$ as required. The $p+1=18$ different solutions to the equation in part (3) are given by
$$
\alpha = (1, \pm 4, 0, 0), (1, 0, \pm 4, 0), (1, 0, 0, \pm 4), (3, \pm 2, \pm 2, 0), (3, \pm 2, 0, \pm 2), (3, 0, \pm 2, \pm 2)
$$
where the $\pm$ signs are independent in the solutions with $a_0=3$. This leads to the set of matrices
$$
\tilde{\alpha} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 0 \\
 0 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 9 \\
 4 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 6 \\
 6 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 7 \\
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
 9 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 8 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 11 \\
 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 3 \\
 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 10 \\
 10 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 2 \\
 11 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 5 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 8 \\
 12 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 5 \\
 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 12 \\
 8 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 11 \\
 2 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 3 \\
 3 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 10 \\
 10 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 2 \\
 11 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Computing the determinants gives $\det(\tilde{\alpha}) \equiv 4 \text{ mod } q$ for all $\alpha$, so it appears to me that these matrices are not elements of $\mathsf{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Z}_q)$ since they do not have determinant $1$.
What is the problem here? It may well be a basic error - I am not at all experienced in this area so my apologies if I am missing something very obvious.

(1)  Lubotzky, A., Phillips, R. & Sarnak, P. Ramanujan graphs. Combinatorica 8, 261–277 (1988)

In ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ you need determinant $1$ but in ${\rm PSL}(2,q),$ non zero scalar multiples are identified, so you only need the determinant of the pre-image to be a non-zero square in the field of $q$ elements. Since the given matrices all have determinant $p$, which is assumed to be a square  (mod $q$), there is no problem,

Said more directly, you want to divide all your matrices by a square root of $p$ modulo $q$ to get matrices in $SL_2$.

Ah of course! Thanks very much
